# Remove characters from file to keep only numbers

Tags: character

I've a text file with many lines like following 5 with leading space.  I would like to delete everything highlighted and only keep.
51
61
66
69
71
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6z7i.png)

TIA for your help.  This is part of a bigger power shell script to kill stale sessions on a server.

Answer (score -1):

I hope someone can improve working script below.  TIA

To get userlist.txt, I'm running....

```
quser /server:XYZSERVERNAME | Out-File $PSScriptRoot\userlist.txt
```

Then following script to sort all Disconnected users then to get only their unique ID.

```
get-content $PSScriptRoot\userlist.txt | select-string -pattern "Disc" | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt

(Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt -Raw) -replace "~.| .*m " -replace "(?m)  D.*.$" -replace "[`r`n]+", "`n" | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt

(gc $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt) | % {$_.trim()} | sc $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt

(Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt) -replace '^.*(?=.{3}$)' | sc $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt

(gc $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt) | % {$_.trim()} | sc $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt

((Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt -Raw) -replace "(?m)^\s*`r`n",'').trim() | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\disc_IDs_list.txt
```